# transmit parameters in websphere portal8.5

Tags: websphere-portal

I have two portlets,in the `view.jsp` of the first portlet have an form.  By clicking submit, parameters can be transmitted to the `show.jsp` of the second portlet.  If submit by 'get', I can receive the parameters.  When I submit by "post", the parameter is null.

What can I do?  Can I directly redirect to the other portlets by setting the `<portlet:URL>` in the `view.jsp`?  If not, by using  `<action:URL>`  transmit parameters to the `processAction` of the current portlet, but how to set in the `processAction` that can redirect to the other portlet?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this is a jsr 286 portlet,  the reason for this has to do with the two phase of the portlet cycle.  In the processaction on the Action response set the methods via setRenderParameter https://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-2.0-apidocs/javax/portlet/ActionResponse.html  If you want you could get the map from the ActionRequest and then just set it to the action response with setRenderParameters

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I used the setRenderParameter in actionResponse ,and i can get the parameters from  renderRequest(--doView()--) of the  current portlet,but how can i jump to the other portlet after setRenderParameter.

Comment: ahh sorry missed that part, if you want to target another portlet with a form so Portlet a has a form and sends the data to another, you can use public render paramters, and if both portlets are listening to those paramters then they will both get them.  You can also use events to send the content over to the other portlet.  Or you can use the advanced url helper classes to target other portlets https://connections.asponte.com/blogs/asppontecom/entry/Portal_8_0_and_8_5_Advanced_URL_Generation_Helper_classes?lang=en_us

Comment: The big thing here is how do you want the flow to be, Do you want it to Form on portlet a-> portlet a process action -> portlet b, or just form on portlet a -> Portlet b. You cannot use the action url to target another portlet on the page, but you can with the advance url helper classes to target another portlet on the page http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSDK36_8.5.0/dev-portlet/pltcom_datxchg_xptltlnks.html  Public render parameters would be the easiest I think